# Invoking FindBugs from Ant: passing a space-separated list of files to java

Tags: ant, findbugs

I'm trying to invoke FindBugs from inside Ant. In order to control the amount of memory available to FindBugs, I've chosen not to use the ant-task. The problem I have now is that I want to pass a number of jars on the command-line to FindBugs:

```
java -jar .../findbugs.jar foo.jar bar.jar fie.jar
```

However, since these jars actually are Eclipse plugins, I don't know the exact name of the jars so I need a way to use a wildcard to obtain the list. This is what I've come up with:

```
<target name="findbugs">
    <property name="findbugs.home" location="${user.home}/eclipse/findbugs" />
    <path id="findbugs.input">
        <fileset dir="${testDirectory}/eclipse/plugins">
            <include name="my.plugins.*.jar" />
        </fileset>
    </path>
    <path id="findbugs.auxinput">
        <fileset dir="${testDirectory}/eclipse/plugins">
            <include name="*.jar" />
            <include name="**/*.jar" />
        </fileset>
    </path>
    <java jar="${findbugs.home}/lib/findbugs.jar" fork="true">
        <jvmarg value="-Xmx1048m" />
        <arg value="-textui" />
        <arg value="-output" />
        <arg value="findbugs.xml" />
        <arg value="-xml" />
        <arg value="-exclude" />
        <arg value="${basedir}/findbugsExclude.xml" />
        <arg value="-auxclasspath" />
        <arg pathref="findbugs.auxinput"/>
        <arg pathref="findbugs.input" />
    </java>
</target>
```

However, the `findbugs.input` pathref is a **comma-separated** list of jars, and not space-separated as FindBugs wants it. How do I get the list of jars as a space-separated list?

(Is this perhaps easier to do with the FindBugs ant-task. I can't really tell from the documentation.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [pathconvert](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/pathconvert.html), like this:

```
<pathconvert pathsep="," property="findbugs.input.csv" refid="findbugs.input"/>
```

Implementing in the target that you provided, I changed the reference from `<arg pathref="findbugs.input" />`
 to `<arg value="${findbugs.input.csv}" />`

```
<target name="findbugs">
    <property name="findbugs.home" location="${user.home}/eclipse/findbugs" />
    <path id="findbugs.input">
        <fileset dir="${testDirectory}/eclipse/plugins">
            <include name="my.plugins.*.jar" />
        </fileset>
    </path>
    <pathconvert pathsep="," property="findbugs.input.csv"
                 refid="findbugs.input"/>

    <path id="findbugs.auxinput">
        <fileset dir="${testDirectory}/eclipse/plugins">
            <include name="*.jar" />
            <include name="**/*.jar" />
        </fileset>
    </path>

    <echo message="${findbugs.input.csv}" />

    <java jar="${findbugs.home}/lib/findbugs.jar" fork="true">
        <jvmarg value="-Xmx1048m" />
        <arg value="-textui" />
        <arg value="-output" />
        <arg value="findbugs.xml" />
        <arg value="-xml" />
        <arg value="-exclude" />
        <arg value="${basedir}/findbugsExclude.xml" />
        <arg value="-auxclasspath" />
        <arg pathref="findbugs.auxinput"/>
        <arg value="${findbugs.input.csv}" />
    </java>
</target>
```

Comment: works for me with `<pathconvert pathsep=" " ...>` and `<arg line="...>`

Answer (score 1):

Use <pathconvert> to convert the path into the proper format, storing it into a property then use <arg value...> instead of <arg pathref...>

Answer (score 0):

You can control the memory from the ant task:

```
    <findbugs   jvmargs="-Xms512m -Xmx512m" ...>
      ...
   </findbugs>
```