# Findbugs ant task submitting several dynamically detected JAR files for analysis

Tags: ant, findbugs

I'm currently looking to run static analysis over a pre-existing project. As the project is created and supplied by an off-site company, I cannot change the build process radically.

The project is split into a lot of sub-modules, located in various places. For other analyisi tools (JDepend, Google Testability Explorer, etc.), I have dynamically detected all build JAR files into a `path` element as follows:

```
<path id="built-libs">
  <fileset dir="${overall-base}">
    <include name="${some-common-base}/**/lib/*.jar" />
  </fileset>
</path>
<property name="built-libs-string" refid="built-libs" />
```

For some tools, I use the `build-libs`, for others I use the string (in classpath form; `x.jar;y.jar`).

The trouble is, FindBugs uses a completely different format to any other;

```
<class location="x.jar"/>
<class location="y.jar"/>
...
```

Now, I could list all the JAR files manually, but then run the risk of this list going out of synch with the other tool's lists, or of introducing typos.

Another complication is that I also want to run the reports in Jenkins, in this case the extract directory for individual modules will depend on the job that has previously built the module (pipeline builds, modules extracted from SCM and built in parallel, the reporting occurring at the end of the pipline).

I *could* make a call out to the OS to run FindBugs, passing in the JARs in a space separated list (as in [Invoking FindBugs from Ant: passing a space-separated list of files to java](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1356418/18744)). However, I prefer a, Ant solution to an OS `<exec...` hack.

*Note* I know I have a similar problem for the `sourcepath` element, however, I'm assuming that solving the `class` element problem also solves the `sourcepath` one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ideally, FindBugs should be taking a [resource collection](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Types/resources.html#collection) rather than separate `class` elements. I'm not familiar with FindBugs, so I can't comment on why they have chose to go the `class` element route instead of a resource collection, however your comment about using `exec` implies that using a resource collection is a valid design alternative.

I would try rolling your own [Ant macro](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/macrodef.html), which [invokes FindBugs directly](http://findbugs.sourceforge.net/manual/running.html#directInvocation) using the [java](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/java.html) task. This should give you the control you need and avoiding the redundancy that the FindBugs Ant task would introduce.

Another option (which is an ugly hack) is to use the `fileset` to write a mini ant file with a FindBugs target, which you then invoke using the [ant](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/ant.html) task. *shudders*

Comment: Yes, I have the list of JARs as a collection already. The problem in defining a macro is that I just don't like the idea of calling out of Ant to run a task that exists in Ant. More a personal peeve, it just feels icky. I might just do this though, if I am forced to, it makes more sense to me than hard coding each JAR.

Comment: @GKelly, I agree calling out via `exec` is "icky", but you shouldn't feel that way about the `java` task. The `java` task just calls a java class within the same JVM (unless you set `fork` to true). Other option ofcourse is to [create your own Ant Task](Writing Your Own Task).

Answer (score 0):

The Findbugs Ant task allows you to specify a filelist which can be used to specify multiple files. Quoting from the [Findbugs documentation](http://findbugs.sourceforge.net/manual/anttask.html)

> "In addition to or instead of specifying a class element, the FindBugs
>   task can contain one or more fileset element(s) that specify files to
>   be analyzed. For example, you might use a fileset to specify that all
>   of the jar files in a directory should be analyzed."

Example that includes all jars at ${lib.dir}:

```
<findbugs home="${findbugs.home}" output="xml" outputFile="findbugs.xml" >
    <auxClasspath path="${basedir}/lib/Regex.jar" />
    <sourcePath path="${basedir}/src/java" />
    <fileset dir="${lib.dir}">
       <include name="*.jar"/>
    </fileset>
</findbugs>
```